# Map Reduce help in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a collection named 'elements' which stores lessons and tracks. The lessons and tracks are differentiated using a field called cms_content_type, which is 'Lesson' for lessons and 'Track' for tracks. There is a cms_id field which uniquely identifies an element, be it a track or a lesson. A track consists of one or more lessons in the track_lessons field.

The structure of a lesson document is:

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('1234'),
    'name': 'Working with Tags',
    'cms_content_type': 'Lesson',
    'cms_id': 'abcd1234'
}
```

The structure of track document is:

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('4567'),
    'name': 'Tags 101',
    'cms_content_type': 'Track',
    'cms_id': 'pqrs4567'
    'track_lessons':[
        {'lesson_cms_id': 'efgh1234'},
        {'lesson_cms_id': 'jklm1234'}
    ]
}
```

I would like to query this elements collection to get a list of lessons that are ***not*** present in any track. How can I achieve this? I'm new to MapReduce. Do I have to use that to get this list?

Another requirement is that I should be able to sort and paginate through the list of lessons retrieved. So I'd prefer to write a dynamic query rather than store results in a separate collection and work on that.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to query this elements collection to get a list of lessons that are not
>   present in any track. How can I achieve this?

You can't use M/R as it only works over one collection. Redesigning a schema is something you of course want to prevent, but right now you have one which is not adequate for your needs. In MongoDB you design your schema according how you use the data, unlike an RDBMs where you design the schema according to normalisation rules

So, by far the easiest way to do this is by storing the `cms_id` of a track as an array with the **lesson** documents:

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('1234'),
    'name': 'Working with Tags',
    'cms_content_type': 'Lesson',
    'cms_id': 'abcd1234',
    'tracks': [ 'pqrs4567' ]
}
```

This way, you don't need to do a cumbersome M/R query and you can query for them as easily as with:

```
db.col.find( { tracks: { $size: 0 } );
```

You shouldn't store them as a nested array as you've done about in the opposite direction either, but instead just store the IDs:

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('4567'),
    'name': 'Tags 101',
    'cms_content_type': 'Track',
    'cms_id': 'pqrs4567'
    'track_lessons': [ 'efgh1234', 'jklm1234' ]
}
```

This makes things a lot more optimal if you create an index on track_lessons (or tracks). But I would recommend you leave the track_lessons out altogether and store the tracks with the lessons instead:

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('1234'),
    'name': 'Working with Tags',
    'cms_content_type': 'Lesson',
    'cms_id': 'abcd1234',
    'tracks': [ 'pqrs4567' ]
}
{
    '_id': ObjectId('4567'),
    'name': 'Tags 101',
    'cms_content_type': 'Track',
    'cms_id': 'pqrs4567'
}
```

Even if you don't store all the lessons belonging to a track (the Tags 101 for example) you can still easily query for all the lessons belonging to the tracks with the following query:

```
db.col.find( { tracks: 'pqrs4567' } );
```

With making these changes you can forget about M/R at all, which makes your app a lot easier to maintain, and faster.

Comment: The collection I have already exists the way I have described. So I would prefer a solution based on the design I've mentioned rather than re-design the collection.

Comment: You can't use M/R as it only works over one collection. Redesigning a schema is something you of course want to prevent, but right now you have one which is not adequate for your needs. In MongoDB you design your schema according how you *use* the data, unlike an RDBMs where you design the schema according to normalisation rules.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that M/R can be of any help here. Because with your current design you will need to check some id from one collection on another collection (i.e. Lessons and Tracks). In M/R you can not run db queries from map reduce functions. Current design is breaking data locality and tends to be more like relational one in terms of foreign key usage. And as a result you will need to pay with performance of your queries (sort of joins). 
Derick's solution tries to overcome this locality problem by including needed information inside each document. And I completely encourage you to put data you need inside one document.

If you must do it with the current design, straightforward solution would be:

```
var lessons_without_task = [];
db.lessons.find().forEach(
   function(lesson_doc) {
      var task = db.tasks.findOne({ "track_lessons.lesson_cms_id" : lesson_doc.cms_id });
      if (task == null) {
        lessons_without_task.push(lesson_doc.cms_id);
      }
   }
)
```

I assume here that you defined multikey index on `track_lessons.lesson_cms_id`. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-multi-key
You might need to add the following options for large collection (right after `find()`)
`addOption(DBQuery.Option.awaitData).addOption(DBQuery.Option.noTimeout)`

Comment: This will probably work, but it's not a good solution (as you say yourself).

Comment: Yes, this approach should be avoided in general, but I gave this example only under assumption of the constraint (no change in document structure) defined by Rainbard.